# PostgreSQL writes several trancations into loop as one transaction with subtransactions

Tags: sql, postgresql, wal

Sometimes, if database is big, PostgreSQL writes inserts in loop as a transaction with  sub transactions into wal file.
For example,

```
begin
for i in 1..10000000 loop
INSERT INTO src.customers
(id, first_name, last_name, email)
values
(i,'Mark', 'Lion', 'mlion@mail.com');
end loop;
end;
```

Here the upper sql sometimes is written as one big transaction with 10000000 subtransactions into wal, for example:

```
rmgr: Transaction len (rec/tot): 168000073/168000073, tx: 2884083787, lsn: C1/C486C9B8, prev C1/C486C870, desc: COMMIT 2024-01-17 12:43:35.646805 UTC; subxacts: 2884083788 2884083791 <many of them>
```

But I expected 10000000 transactions or only one transaction without subtransactions in wal file. Do you know there exists some postgresql parameter to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you expect multiple transactions? A single function-call/do-loop is always one transaction without explicit transaction ends

Comment: There are no subtransactions in your example. Please explain in some more detail what you mean, and where you see these subtransactions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I'm parsing wal file, and postgres writes this loop inserts as one transaction with subtrancastions.

Comment: If the code that you show is PL/pgSQL code, then no, it won't generate subtransactions. You must be misreading the WAL (or the code you are executing is actually different).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added pg_waldump output. This is correct: rmgr: Transaction len (rec/tot): 168000073/168000073, tx: 2884083787, lsn: C1/C486C9B8, prev C1/C486C870, desc: COMMIT 2024-01-17 12:43:35.646805 UTC; subxacts: 2884083788 2884083791 <many of them>

Comment: I repeated your example, and I see no subtransactions. You must be running code different from what you show. Is there perhaps an `EXCEPTION` clause somewhere? That would explain what you see.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I found in file clog.c line 196-209 - this code shows setting subtransaction:   /*
   * If this is a commit then we care about doing this correctly (i.e.
   * using the subcommitted intermediate status).  By here, we know
   * we're updating more than one page of clog, so we must mark entries
   * that are *not* on the first page so that they show as subcommitted
   * before we then return to update the status to fully committed.
   *
   * To avoid touching the first page twice, skip marking subcommitted
   * for the subxids on that first page.
   */ Can be this as cause?

Comment: This is about the commit log, not the transaction log. Unless you show your actual code, I cannot help you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , thank you. I'm using open postgresql 15 version, this behavior happens sometime, not always or when db is busy, I don't know.

Comment: No information, no answer possible.